# How to write these formulas and equations

Tags: symbols, align, syntax

How can I write this formula:

1) [image]
I have tried to use `$ \stackrel {}{}$` but it does not give the right form.

And how to align these equations

2) [image]
3) [image]

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x^\pm=\max\{\pm x,0\}$
\end{document}`

Comment: This is several questions, but: 1. ± is `\pm`.

Comment: 2.: *û* in math mode is `\hat{u}` Greek letters are `\beta`, `\zeta`, and so on.

Comment: 3. ∆ might be `\Delta` or if you use `unicode-math` (which I recommend), `\increment`. The lambda-with-a-hat is `\hat{\lambda}`. Add `\usepackage{mathtools}`. You would write the two cases inside a `\begin{cases} ... \end{cases}` block.  Write `&\text{ in } \Omega \\ ` and `&\text{ on } \partial\Omega`.

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to read some tutorials on writing math in LaTeX before asking here. There are a lot of these online and in the documentation. For example, see [the AMS page](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/tex/amslatex) and the links therein. You can start with short tutorials like the [Short Math Guide for LaTeX](http://ctan.yazd.ac.ir/info/short-math-guide/short-math-guide.pdf). Any way, here is a small help from me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\[
x^\pm = \max\{\pm x, 0\}
\]
and
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega}\left(|D \hat{u}|^{p-2} D \hat{u}-|D \tilde{u}|^{p-2} D \tilde{u}, D \hat{u}-D \tilde{u}\right)_{\mathbb{R}^{N}}dz\\
&\quad{}+\hat{\xi} \int_{\Omega}\left(|\hat{u}|^{p-2} \hat{u}-|\tilde{u}|^{p-2} \tilde{u}\right)(\hat{u}-\tilde{u})dz\\
&\quad{}+\int_{\partial \Omega} \beta(z)\left(|\hat{u}|^{p-2} \hat{u}-|\tilde{u}|^{p-2} \tilde{u}\right)(\hat{u}-\tilde{u}) d\sigma=0
\end{align*}
and
\[
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta_p u(z) &= \hat{\lambda}|u(z)|^{p-2} u(z),  && \text { in } \Omega \\ 
\frac{\partial u}{\partial n_p}+\beta(z)|u|^{p-2}u &= 0, && \text { on } \partial \Omega.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\]

\end{document}
```

> [image]